# Fragment caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to fragment cache part of a page.
On the view I have

```
<% cache("saved_area") do %>
.
 <% end -%>
```

In the controller:

```
  def index 

   read_fragment("saved_area")

   end
```

In config/production:

```
   config.cache_store = :file_store, File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'tmp', 'cache')
```

The file was created in the tmp/cache directory.  But I am not sure if the cache is being used in the request, since I presume there should be a line in the log stating that the cache is being used (and there is not).

Answer (score 2):

Rails sets the log level in production mode to `:info`, hence it does not log cache hits and misses. If you set

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

in your `config/enviroments/production.rb`, then you see messages like:

```
Cached fragment hit: views/test (0.2ms)
Cached fragment miss: views/test (1.8ms)
```

in your log. The second solution is to configure your development environment to perform caching, since `:debug` is the default log level in this environment. This can be done by setting:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :file_store, File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'tmp', 'cache')
```

This is the best way to do this, since if your app goes into production, you won't log that much.

BTW: You don't have to call `read_fragment` in your controller. The `cache` helper method will do this for you.